# How to make an average formula only count numbers greater than zero?

Tags: excel, if-statement, count, sum, average

`=AVERAGE(K2:K32)`

I have this formula spitting out an average for coulmn K as you can see. The problem I am having is that the numbers in column K are populated by a formula basically adding two other columns together so if no data is entered the number returned is 0. This obviously throws off an average calculation for a month that is not complete, how can I make this formula only count the numbers which are greater than zero?

Answer (score 11):

```
=AVERAGEIF(K2:K32, ">0")
```

Here is the example formula, which includes cells having value > 0.

Comment: what about it? OP asked for "only count the numbers which are greater than zero"

Comment: I have tried the above formula =AVERAGEIF(K2:K32, ">0") and where the average is populated I get the answer "true" I think this is because the formula may only be correct if every blank is in fact filled in. I need an average formula which will basically ignore any cell with zero as a value and only average the numbers in the range K2:k32 if they are in fact greater than the value 0.

Comment: Can you try this formula on a separate sheet? I am unable to understand the reason for it to show True. Does the range K2:K32 contain values other than numbers?

Comment: The only thing column K has is a formula in each cell, example =E2+I2. That number is then used to get a total for the month at the bottom of column K as well as an average, the only problem is with the zeroes being populated in the cells which are in fact at zero is throwing my average number off until the last day of the month, I would like it to update every day is all.

Comment: The formula is simple. I am unable to understand why it returns true?

Comment: @shahkalpesh I am also confused, it seems rather simple to me as well.

Comment: Try the formula on a new workbook and you'll see that it works. Do you have any VBA code or formatting in place that modified the value? Do you see the formula in the formula bar? Do a clear-all on the cell before applying the formula and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention *an average calculation for a month that is not complete* and that *the numbers in column K are populated by a formula basically adding two other columns together* if either of the numbers being added could be negative it seems possible that the formula may return `0` even for that part of the month that is complete, so strictly speaking a `0` in that case should be taken into account for a true average. Hence, assuming one of the numbers being added is in ColumnE (which will be blank or `0` for the incomplete part of the month) I suggest an array formula such as:

```
 =AVERAGE(IF(E2:E32<>0,K2:K32))
```

entered with Ctrl+Shift+Enter. For months with less than 31 days enter a value other than `0` into ColumnE for the non-existent days.

Answer (score -1):

You must use:

```
=AVERAGEIF(K2:K32,">0")
```

Make sure there are no spaces in the formula.

Comment: In how does this add something to the existing answer?